# How to disable html button using JSTL tags

Tags: spring, jstl

I want disable HTML button depending on value present in Spring bean.I am using JSTL `empty` property but no luck.
Here is my code

```
   <input type="submit" value="SendEmail" disabled="${empty reportNotificationFbo.providersList}" >
```

Here `reportNotificationFbo` is spring bean and `providersList` is a list.

I want to disable `Submit` button if `providersList` is empty.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

State of the button is controlled by the presence of `disabled` attribute, not by its value. Try the following:

```
<input type="submit" value="SendEmail"
    "${(empty reportNotificationFbo.providersList) ? 'disabled' : ''}" >
```

Comment: Thanks axtavt :) Got things on right place :) Thanks again :)

Comment: Just a note, this doesn't work for me, I get a `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unterminated &lt;stripes:select tag`

Comment: You don't really want the quotes around that, do you?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me too. Getting the error Unterminated [&lt;form:input] tag.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `disabled` attribute with *any value* it will be rendered in the browser as disabled

Try

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty reportNotificationFbo.providersList}">
        <input type="submit" value="SendEmail" disabled="disabled" >
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
       <input type="submit" value="SendEmail"  >
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Sorry i haven't checked this code

Comment: Thanks Reevesy. Above answer is working. Will try yours also but right now I am running out of time. Thanks :)

Comment: Both methods should work. The Reason that disabled="false" does not work is that the HTML disabled attribute with ANY value (including false) will make the button disabled. This is part of the original html spec where the attribute value is not actually required. This is explained here http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/HTML-And-XHTML-Boolean-Attributes/

Comment: What if my </input> does not come until after the choose? It will throw an error.

Comment: @JL Might be worth you posting up your markup as a question on S.O. (if you haven't already), from what I see you are using stripes....

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a `<stripes:select>` tag, and it seems neither of these answers work. We solved it by switching it to an `<input>`

Comment: Ok fella, It might still be worth posting up and answering your own question, it might help someone out down the line......