# How to re-enable HTML <select> using EL?

Tags: html, el

I want to be able to disable and re-enable a `<select>` on a certain condition with EL, much like this [example](https://booking.cititrans.co.id/online/booking). In the example, the list From will be disabled if you haven't chosen any City yet. I know how to disable a `<select>` from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029475/how-to-disable-html-button-using-jstl-tags), but how to re-enable them ?

This is my code so far, as you can see the monthcmb will be disabled if yearcmb's value is 'Select year' which is default

```
<SELECT class="drop" name="yearcmb" required >
        <option value="">Select year</option>
    </SELECT>

    <SELECT class="drop" name="monthcmb" required ${(empty yearcmb) ? 'disabled' : ''}>
        <option value="">Select month</option>
    </SELECT>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically disable html <select> in JSTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229675/how-to-dynamically-disable-html-select-in-jstl)

Comment: Please look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11231228/5813861) given by @BalusC

Comment: @yash yes i've seen that question, and i tried the answer as you can see from my code. However, it's either i don't fully understand or it doesn't work in my case. Kindly let me know how can i implement it in my case